# Get User and group details using NTLM authentication

Tags: c#, ntlm

I want to get all user and group details using **NTLM** authentication.

Does NTLM use **Active Directory** for storing all usernames? Are NTLM and **Windows Authentication** the same authentication methods?

If yes, then what is the use of the **domain** in this case?

Answer (score 5):

> Does **NTLM** use **Active Directory** for storing all usernames?

Yes, usernames are stored in Active Directory. NTLM just a challenge/response authentication protocol in which the client never sends the password over the wire.

> Are NTLM and **Windows Authentication** the same authentication methods?

Yes, there are many names that refer to this same authentication mechanism:

- HTTP Negotiate authentication
- NT Authentication
- NTLM Authentication
- Domain authentication
- Windows Integrated Authentication
- Windows NT Challenge/Response authentication

or simply

- Windows Authentication.

> If yes, then what is the use of the **domain** in this case?

As mentioned earlier the client never sends his password over the wire. So in order to ensure the identity of the client, the server communicates with the domain controller in order to challenge the client to which if the client responds successfully it means that he is the one who he claims to be.

Now back to your original question:

> I want to get all user and group details using **NTLM** authentication.

You need to query your domain controller (AD) in order to retrieve this information. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5310317/29407) that shows how to get the groups given a username.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Darin. from your link System.Web.HttpContext.Current giving me null exception.what am i doing wrong?another thing, i need to get all users. is there any example for query the domain controller to get the list of all users?

Comment: Are you developing an ASP.NET application. `HttpContext.Current` can only be used inside an ASP.NET application.