# GetAuthorizationGroups returns more groups than my user is in

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, userprincipal

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net) post to get the security groups of a user.

I had to change it a bit so it looks like this:

```
public List<GroupPrincipal> GetGroups(string userName, string userPassword, string userDomain)
    {
        List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

        // establish domain context
        PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, userDomain, userName, userPassword);

        // find your user
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);

        // if found - grab its groups
        if (user != null)
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

            // iterate over all groups
            foreach (Principal p in groups)
            {
                // make sure to add only group principals
                if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                {
                    result.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Unfortunately I now get every security group in the AD and not only the ones the user is in. 
My user is in 10 groups but it returns 71.
I had to submit username and password or else I would not be allowed to look up the groups. It is an administrative account on a different domain so I couldn't use the current credentials.

If you need more info please let me know.

Greetings and thanks in advance
IG

Answer (score 1):

Is there a chance that the 10 groups are members of other groups?  According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups Method**
>
> This method searches all groups recursively and returns the groups in which the user is a
> member. The returned set may also include additional groups that
> system would consider the user a member of for authorization purposes.