# GetAuthorizationGroups() wrongly assumes I´m an domain administrator

Tags: c#, authentication, c#-4.0, active-directory

I have a domain group name and have to check if a domain user is part of it recursively. After getting my users domain prinical I try to get through all authorization groups

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
     UserPrincipal userPrin = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userToCheck);
     if (userPrin != null)
     {
         foreach (GroupPrincipal group in userPrin.GetAuthorizationGroups())
         {
               if (group.Name.Equals(groupName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
               { 
                    if (group.Context.Name.StartsWith(domain, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                       return true;
                    }
               }
        }
    }
}
```

[I know, the startsWith might not be the best way but everything work like a a charm]

Only problem: I have two accounts that are both NOT part of the builtin administrators group of the domain. Both user principals are found and the groups are enumerated but:
For one user the result is FALSE when checking builtin administrators group
For one user the result is TRUE when checking builtin administrators group

I know that the group checked is indeed the correct domain object for both tries.

Why does it say the one account is in that group?

## UPDATE

When searching via cmd (net user /domain) the group does NOT show up.
When running the code from another machine (same user is queries) the group does also not show up.
But if you query the current user that is logged in as an administrator this user is considered to be in the group

```
CN=Administratoren,CN=Builtin,DC=domain,DC=de
```

which is just wrong. He might be in the local group but definetly NOT in the domain administrators group.
The SID of the group is *S-1-5-32-544* btw.

## UPDATE2

Since PrincipalContext internally uses the DirectorySearcher I tried to have a solution with the directory searcher. It returns only the correct groups.  (although I´m not sure right now if it has a function für recursive group search like Principle context has)

So either this is a bug or has something to do with the **additional groups**  like *dlatikay* pointed out

> This method searches all groups recursively and returns the groups in which the user is a member. The returned set may also include additional groups that system would consider the user a member of for authorization purposes.
>
> The groups that are returned by this method may include groups from a different scope and store than the principal. For example, if the principal is an AD DS object that has a DN of "CN=SpecialGroups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com, the returned set can contain groups that belong to the "CN=NormalGroups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com.

But why does it return additional groups, I have to make sure the user really is privileged in the groups returned.

Comment: Are you *sure* the user isn't in any group named 'Administrators'? The group name is unique in its OU. So there might be another 'Administrators' group in your AD. Check the `DistinguishedName` of the group when it matches to be sure.

Comment: Did you verify by other means too? like http://serverfault.com/a/532107/387902

Comment: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19178866/1132334) related, [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22815573/1132334) would not apply

Comment: Yes, I checked the DistinguishedName and identified the exact administrators group... the user is not in this group or a subgroup

Comment: When I type in net user /domain <username> I get all groups I´m in. The administrators group is NOT listed. I found out: When I rund the code on a different machine but query the same user the group does not show up as well

Comment: regarding your last update on OP: if it is in the "Administratoren" group, [this strongly suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726982.aspx) that  he may well be in the Domain Admins group too: "the Administrator local user is a member of Domain Admins by default. This means that if someone **logs on to a computer as the administrator** and the **computer is a member of the domain**, the user will have complete access to all resources in the domain. To prevent this, you can remove the local Administrator account from the Domain Admins group."

Comment: + there is a hot lead in [original documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups(v=vs.110).aspx), remarks section: "The returned set may also **include additional groups** that system would consider the user a member of **for authorization purposes**."

Comment: @dlatikay isn't it the other way around? DomainAdmins are part of the local admin group and can be removed but there is no local admin link in any domain admin group. Or do you mean a group policy
Yes, I read that part but didn`t assume it would have somthing to do with my problem. But I´ll dig deeper in the authorization group (see update 2)

Comment: I recommend you to check the following: try to log on under the problematic user to a domain controller. By default only admins are allowed to logon (you can check allow log on locally policy). Open ADUC, find the user in case and check it's tokenGroups attribute. It will show all groups the user belongs to. There may be a situation where user belongs to group A, and group A belongs to Administrators group.

Comment: I will try to gain the permission to logon locally, how do I check the tokenGroups attribute when I´m in AD Users&Computers?

Comment: Try to log on without gaining permission. If the problematic user can logon, then he belongs to some admins group. To view tokenGroups you need to enable advanced features option in aduc. Then right click on the user, select properties and go to the attribute editor tab

Comment: @oldovets The TokenGroups show the same groups as I get with the  DirectorySearcher or the cmd.exe net command. But still when I query with a domain user, I get the builtin/admin group of the domain as an authorization group

Comment: Looked at the source code of GetAuthorizationGroups. It calls Authz API under the hood (AuthzInitializeContextFromSid, AuthzGetInformationFromContext). For some reason AuthzGetInformationFromContext function returns you builtin\administrators. Do you run your code under the problematic user (userToCheck in your code sample), or under some other user? If you run it under the problematic user UAC might be the case. Anyway, you can try to reproduce the issue by calling AuthzApi via pinvoke. You can also write your own group checker based on querying tokenGroups attribute and SID resolving.

Comment: Turned out to be not one problematic user but if the queried user is the logged on user with local admin rights (see update). Since I tried to find a fix for quiet some days now I just used the .GetGroups() function and made it recursive. This will just return the groups I really am in and is only a few lines of additional programming. Sad though