# Retrieving the local group name by which a particular user belongs to

Tags: c#, usergroups

I want to retrieve the local group name by which a particular user belongs to. IE, suppose if we know the user and don't know his/her group name in such case i want to retrieve the group name.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows/Active Directory users?

Comment: yes. Windows. about the local groups and local users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same classes/libraries that can be used to retrieve such information for within an Active Directory domain can be used to retrieve this information from the local machine.

You can use the `PrincipalContext` class, and related classes to retrieve information about users, groups and much more. The constructor of the `PrincipalContext` class allows you to specify a context to search in.

By initializing the `PrincipalContext` class like this:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine,Environment.MachineName);
```

You will operate within your local machine's context. Using the related classes and functions that the `PrincipalContext` class exposes, you can accomplish what you want.

Here is a reference on how to get a list of groups a user is a member of:

[How to get the groups of a user in Active Directory? (c#, asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net)

Even though the link above explains how to do this for an active directory. It still uses the `PrincipalContext` class. It's just a way of modifying how you initialize the instance.