# Return a list of all Active Directory groups a user belongs to in string[ ]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, active-directory

I need to return all Active Directory groups a user belongs to but in string[ ], so I can use the result in Generic Principal.

I am not sure if to cast results? Please help!

```
string[] roles = new string[] {  
helper.GetActiveDirectoryGroups(User.Identity.Name) };

GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity,roles);

 public string[] GetActiveDirectoryGroups(string userName)
    {
          //code here

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the groups of a user in Active Directory? (c#, asp.net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net)

Comment: Yes 'How to get the groups of a User in Active Directory' is helpful but it returns an array list. I need a string[] to satisfy my requirement. Any idea???

Comment: You can write a linq query to get the name of ad group from List.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public static string[] GetGroups(string username)
{
    string[] output = null;

    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            output = user.GetGroups() //this returns a collection of principal objects
                .Select(x => x.SamAccountName) // select the name.  you may change this to choose the display name or whatever you want
                .ToArray(); // convert to string array
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed David! Exactly what i was looking for. The ToArray() converts the collection of principal objects to a string array.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This works with the exception of not recursively checking groups

Comment: if you want to get all the nested groups instead of GetGroups() use GetAuthorizationGroups()

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to return a bool value if user belongs to a group, here it go:

```
 string[] output = null;
            using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username))
            {
                if (user != null)
                {
                    output = user.GetGroups()
                        .Select(x => x.SamAccountName)
                        .ToArray();
                }

                bool isMember = output.Any(groupName.Contains);
            }
```