# C# Console Application - Get Current User AD Groups

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm writing a script to get a list of the current user's AD Groups and creates a .txt file to a Path.

I've had a look around and it seems like I should be using these references:

`using System.DirectoryServices;`
`using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;`

I'm also using this:

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "<Domain>"), IdentityType.SamAccountName, "<UserName>");
foreach (GroupPrincipal group in user.GetGroups())
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(group);
}
```

But this doesn't quite list all the groups that the user should be in.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this block of code to get the user groups:

```
        String domainName = @"<your domain>";
        String username = domainName + @"\<your username>";
        PrincipalContext thisDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(thisDomain, username);

        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> userGroups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();

        foreach (Principal principal in userGroups.OfType<GroupPrincipal>())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(principal.Name);
        }
```

As far as I can tell, it lists all the groups the user is a member of by comparison to what is held in Active Directory and looking at the user object in the MMC snap in

Comment: Doing a comparison between the two methods, with mine I get 21 extra groups being listed at my companies Forest/Domain/AD setup. Don't know why the differences exist though.