# active directory- see that user is admin c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I see if user is admin or not in active directory using c#? Getting his  groups names is not an option, because in different languages this roles names are different (администраторы, administrators, etc)

Comment: do you mean to check from the program itself if the user is admin or not?
i dont know about active directory..

Comment: I have intranet site. Users login there with Windows authentification. Admin or not - how much permissions he will have. Active directory is a way to get user roles

Answer (score 1):

> How can I see if user is admin or not in active directory using c#?

I assume that "admin in active directory" means a literal admin of AD (ie. a member of the builtin `Administrators` group)

The built-in Administrators group will *always* have the same RID (*relative identifier*) - the last part of the object's security identifier - `544`.

A sure-fire way to find the Administrators group is therefore straightforward:

1. Instantiate a DirectoryEntry for the root object of the Default NC
2. Read the objectSID attribute value on the root object
3. Append the well-known RID (`-544`)
4. Instantiate a DirectoryEntry based on the resulting SID (yes, you can do that)

---

```
DirectoryEntry dnc = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://corp.domain.tld");
SecurityIdentifier domainSID = new SecurityIdentifier(dnc.Properties["objectSid"].Value);

string administratorsGroupSID = String.Format("{0}-544", domainSID);
string administratorsGroupSIDPath = String.Format("LDAP://<SID={0}>", administratorsGroupSID);

DirecoryEntry AdministratorsGroupDE = new DirectoryEntry(administratorsGroupSIDPath);
```

Grab th

Answer (score 0):

Vlad,

Querying AD to retrieve members of the Admin group has been asked before...

Server 2003 [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/9922/how-do-i-tell-if-a-certain-ad-user-has-admin-rights-on-windows-server-2003) as well as [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284730/check-if-user-is-part-of-administrator-group-c-sharp)

Since your question seems to be concerned about differentiating the character string for "Administrator" in the installed language, wouldn't you simply have locale specific names for this in your resources/code?