# Recursive method throws unspecified error on PropertyValueCollection assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, active-directory

I am making an ASP.NET intranet website that uses Active Directory and I am trying to get all the groups a user belongs to, even sub groups etc ... So that means I had to make a recursive method to load all the groups in an ArrayList following the example given here : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Hence I have a method to recursively fill an ArrayList based on group membership:

```
public ArrayList AttributeValuesMultiString(string attributeName, string objectDn, 
                                            ArrayList valuesCollection, bool recursive)
{
    DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(objectDn);
    PropertyValueCollection valueCollection = ldapConnection.Properties[attributeName];
    IEnumerator en = valueCollection.GetEnumerator();

    while (en.MoveNext())
    {
        if (en.Current != null)
        {
            if (!valuesCollection.Contains(en.Current.ToString()))
            {
                valuesCollection.Add(en.Current.ToString());
                if (recursive)
                {
                    AttributeValuesMultiString(attributeName, "LDAP://" +
                    en.Current.ToString(), valuesCollection, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ldapConnection.Close();
    ldapConnection.Dispose();
    return valuesCollection;
}
```

That I call from this other method:

```
public ArrayList Groups(string userDn, bool recursive)
{
    ArrayList groupMemberships = new ArrayList();
    return AttributeValuesMultiString("memberOf", userDn, groupMemberships, recursive);
}
```

Using the `recursive` boolean I can build my group's arraylist, but the first method can be used for other multistring object loading. Now when I test this just by a simple call to the method

```
//adManager is an instance of the class containing the methods above
//groups is an ArrayList
//testChain is my distinguishedName
groups = adManager.Groups(testChain, true);
foreach (var g in groups)
    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
```

I have the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Unspecified error
```

And the point at which I have the exception is at the assignment:

```
PropertyValueCollection valueCollection = ldapConnection.Properties[attributeName];
```

I really don't see the problem, especially that this method was recommended on another SO thread, so I'm guessing it's functional

**EDIT** Seems that my problem comes from an authentication issue. I added impersonation in my test code but I still get an exception :

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
    var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "radiofrance.rootad.inetrf");
    var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.Name, "Users");
    if (groupPrincipal != null)
    {
        groups = adManager.Groups(testChain, true);
        foreach (var g in groups)
            Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Fail");
}
```

Comment: If you have a user distinguished name, you can load tokenGroups attribute which contains all groups (including nested groups) which user belongs to. The only thing that you have to perform is to resolve group sids, as tokenGroups is a collection of sids. To do that you can bind to each group in the list using sid binding via DirectoryEntry.

Comment: The problem with you code is that you have to retrieve memberOf user attribute, then expand members attribute of each group in the list. memberOf attribute does not contain neither groups from other domains not user primary group

Comment: @oldovets About token groups, in this kind of way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4460658/4714502 I didn't know that about memberOf, will try with tokenGroups

Comment: @oldovets Well that solved it thanks!

Comment: @oldovets If you can give an example of tokenGroups i'll mark it as answer, otherwise I'll write it down.

Comment: The example you provided is fine